# Summing up values in a Nested Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, nested

I need write a program that will give the the total profit/losses from the following nested dictionary:

```
[
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":867884
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":984655
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":322013
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":-69417
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":310503
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":522857
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":1033096
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":604885
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":-216386
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":477532
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":893810
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2010",
      "Profit/Losses":-80353
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":779806
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":-335203
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":697845
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":793163
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":485070
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":584122
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":62729
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":668179
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":899906
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":834719
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":132003
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2011",
      "Profit/Losses":309978
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":-755566
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":1170593
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":252788
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":1151518
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":817256
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":570757
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":506702
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":-1022534
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":475062
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":779976
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":144175
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2012",
      "Profit/Losses":542494
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":359333
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":321469
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":67780
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":471435
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":565603
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":872480
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":789480
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":999942
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":-1196225
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":268997
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":-687986
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2013",
      "Profit/Losses":1150461
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":682458
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":617856
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":824098
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":581943
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":132864
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":448062
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":689161
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":800701
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":1166643
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":947333
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":578668
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2014",
      "Profit/Losses":988505
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":1139715
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":1029471
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":687533
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":-524626
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":158620
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":87795
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":423389
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":840723
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":568529
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":332067
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":989499
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2015",
      "Profit/Losses":778237
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":650000
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":-1100387
   },
   {
      "Date":"Mar-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":-174946
   },
   {
      "Date":"Apr-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":757143
   },
   {
      "Date":"May-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":445709
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jun-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":712961
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jul-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":-1163797
   },
   {
      "Date":"Aug-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":569899
   },
   {
      "Date":"Sep-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":768450
   },
   {
      "Date":"Oct-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":102685
   },
   {
      "Date":"Nov-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":795914
   },
   {
      "Date":"Dec-2016",
      "Profit/Losses":60988
   },
   {
      "Date":"Jan-2017",
      "Profit/Losses":138230
   },
   {
      "Date":"Feb-2017",
      "Profit/Losses":671099
   }
]
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?? Please show us your approach to this problem... Please edit them in the post and add relevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Python, so that's what I'm going with.  All I'm doing is using `functools.reduce` to iterate over the array, pulling out the `Profit/Losses` element out of each dictionary.  The `acc` variable is an "accumulator", which starts from the `0` I provide as the third argument to reduce, and is used to hold the result as the iteration over the array happens.

A less "clever" version is to use a list comprehension: `sum([val['Profit/Losses'] for val in vals])` .

```
In [1]: vals=[{'Date': 'Jan-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 867884}, {'Date': 'Feb-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 984655}, {'Date': 'Ma
   ...: r-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 322013}, {'Date': 'Apr-2010', 'Profit/Losses': -69417}, {'Date': 'May-2010', 'Profit/L
   ...: osses': 310503}, {'Date': 'Jun-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 522857}, {'Date': 'Jul-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 1033096}, 
   ...: {'Date': 'Aug-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 604885}, {'Date': 'Sep-2010', 'Profit/Losses': -216386}, {'Date': 'Oct-201
   ...: 0', 'Profit/Losses': 477532}, {'Date': 'Nov-2010', 'Profit/Losses': 893810}, {'Date': 'Dec-2010', 'Profit/Losses
   ...: ': -80353}, {'Date': 'Jan-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 779806}, {'Date': 'Feb-2011', 'Profit/Losses': -335203}, {'Dat
   ...: e': 'Mar-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 697845}, {'Date': 'Apr-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 793163}, {'Date': 'May-2011', 'P
   ...: rofit/Losses': 485070}, {'Date': 'Jun-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 584122}, {'Date': 'Jul-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 627
   ...: 29}, {'Date': 'Aug-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 668179}, {'Date': 'Sep-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 899906}, {'Date': 'Oct
   ...: -2011', 'Profit/Losses': 834719}, {'Date': 'Nov-2011', 'Profit/Losses': 132003}, {'Date': 'Dec-2011', 'Profit/Lo
   ...: sses': 309978}, {'Date': 'Jan-2012', 'Profit/Losses': -755566}, {'Date': 'Feb-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 1170593}, 
   ...: {'Date': 'Mar-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 252788}, {'Date': 'Apr-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 1151518}, {'Date': 'May-201
   ...: 2', 'Profit/Losses': 817256}, {'Date': 'Jun-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 570757}, {'Date': 'Jul-2012', 'Profit/Losses
   ...: ': 506702}, {'Date': 'Aug-2012', 'Profit/Losses': -1022534}, {'Date': 'Sep-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 475062}, {'Da
   ...: te': 'Oct-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 779976}, {'Date': 'Nov-2012', 'Profit/Losses': 144175}, {'Date': 'Dec-2012', '
   ...: Profit/Losses': 542494}, {'Date': 'Jan-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 359333}, {'Date': 'Feb-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 32
   ...: 1469}, {'Date': 'Mar-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 67780}, {'Date': 'Apr-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 471435}, {'Date': 'Ma
   ...: y-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 565603}, {'Date': 'Jun-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 872480}, {'Date': 'Jul-2013', 'Profit/L
   ...: osses': 789480}, {'Date': 'Aug-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 999942}, {'Date': 'Sep-2013', 'Profit/Losses': -1196225},
   ...:  {'Date': 'Oct-2013', 'Profit/Losses': 268997}, {'Date': 'Nov-2013', 'Profit/Losses': -687986}, {'Date': 'Dec-20
   ...: 13', 'Profit/Losses': 1150461}, {'Date': 'Jan-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 682458}, {'Date': 'Feb-2014', 'Profit/Loss
   ...: es': 617856}, {'Date': 'Mar-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 824098}, {'Date': 'Apr-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 581943}, {'Da
   ...: te': 'May-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 132864}, {'Date': 'Jun-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 448062}, {'Date': 'Jul-2014', '
   ...: Profit/Losses': 689161}, {'Date': 'Aug-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 800701}, {'Date': 'Sep-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 11
   ...: 66643}, {'Date': 'Oct-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 947333}, {'Date': 'Nov-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 578668}, {'Date': '
   ...: Dec-2014', 'Profit/Losses': 988505}, {'Date': 'Jan-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 1139715}, {'Date': 'Feb-2015', 'Profi
   ...: t/Losses': 1029471}, {'Date': 'Mar-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 687533}, {'Date': 'Apr-2015', 'Profit/Losses': -52462
   ...: 6}, {'Date': 'May-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 158620}, {'Date': 'Jun-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 87795}, {'Date': 'Jul-2
   ...: 015', 'Profit/Losses': 423389}, {'Date': 'Aug-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 840723}, {'Date': 'Sep-2015', 'Profit/Loss
   ...: es': 568529}, {'Date': 'Oct-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 332067}, {'Date': 'Nov-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 989499}, {'Da
   ...: te': 'Dec-2015', 'Profit/Losses': 778237}, {'Date': 'Jan-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 650000}, {'Date': 'Feb-2016', '
   ...: Profit/Losses': -1100387}, {'Date': 'Mar-2016', 'Profit/Losses': -174946}, {'Date': 'Apr-2016', 'Profit/Losses':
   ...:  757143}, {'Date': 'May-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 445709}, {'Date': 'Jun-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 712961}, {'Date':
   ...:  'Jul-2016', 'Profit/Losses': -1163797}, {'Date': 'Aug-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 569899}, {'Date': 'Sep-2016', 'Pr
   ...: ofit/Losses': 768450}, {'Date': 'Oct-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 102685}, {'Date': 'Nov-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 7959
   ...: 14}, {'Date': 'Dec-2016', 'Profit/Losses': 60988}, {'Date': 'Jan-2017', 'Profit/Losses': 138230}, {'Date': 'Feb-
   ...: 2017', 'Profit/Losses': 671099}]                                                                                

In [2]: from functools import reduce                                                                                    

In [3]: reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + val['Profit/Losses'], vals, 0)                                                    
Out[3]: 38382578
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use Python3 as it is probably the easiest way to compute the result.

Given the dictionary has been named 'name_of_dictionary', we can compute the result as follows:

```
sum(i['Profit/Losses'] for i in name_of_dictionary)
```